# Is it possible to add service redirect in development mode in Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, proxy

I'm working on an App in Angular 6. When the app is deployed, it exchanges data with an online database. When I'm working on the app, however, I would like it to exchange data with a local database. I have a single service setup to do all of the communication, so when I am working on the app I can simply change the base URL, but I was wondering if there was a way I could just redirect that service in development, and then have it go to the database as normal in the production environment.

I am aware I can add a proxy.conf.json file, which I'm already doing to access a separate online API, so I dont know if it is as simple as just adding another element to that json file.

I haven't posted any sample code as this is more of a general question as to methodology in angular versus a specific line of code question, but I'm happy to post whatever people would like to see for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing,

you can configure your url in both `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` like

```
environment = {
...
url: 'something.com/api',
...
}
```

and use it like

```
import { environment } from 'environment/environment';

const url = environment.url;
```

this will give you different url for normal build (Development env.) and prod build (Deploy env.)

Also, don't worry about using just environmet.ts in import statement, as when you create prod build your environment.ts gets content from environment.prod.ts. so you will be using url from environment.prod.ts

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you have access to a function `isDevMode()` which determines if the app is currently in devmode.

Based on that, you should be able to adjust your base url as needed.

```
 import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
  private baseUrl: string = '';
    const devUrl: string = '...';
    const prodUrl: string = '...';

    if (isDevMode()) {
          this.baseUrl = devUrl
        }
        else {
          this.baseUrl = prodUrl
          };
```